# How to evaluate this integral $I=\int^{b}_{0}\sqrt{a-x^6}dx$

Tags: integration

How to evaluate this integral

$$I=\int^{b}_{0}\sqrt{a-x^6}dx$$

Initially I tried substituting $x^3=\sin(t)$, but the integral becomes messy when finding $dx$.  so is there any trick to evaluate this integral?

Comment: This is probably leading to some messy elliptic integrals.

Comment: But your biggest problem is not that integral, but that your instructors conditioned you to put trigonometric functions inside integrals with radicals. That's rarely a good idea.

Comment: Maybe useful:$$
a-x^6=(\sqrt[3]{a})^3-{(x^2)}^3=(\sqrt[3]{a}-{x^2})
\,(\sqrt[3]{a^2}+\sqrt[3]{a}\,x^2+x^4)=
$$
$$
(\sqrt[3]{a}-{x^2})\,({(x^2+\sqrt[3]{a})}^2-\sqrt[3]{a}\,x^2)
=\,(\sqrt[3]{a}-{x^2})\,(x^2+\sqrt[6]{a}\,x+\sqrt[3]{a})\,
(x^2-\sqrt[6]{a}\,x+\sqrt[3]{a})
$$

Comment: It's not integrable in finite terms $I=b\sqrt{a}  \, _2F_1\left(-\frac{1}{2},\frac{1}{6};\frac{7}{6};\frac{b^6}{a}\right)$

Comment: If we expand (a- x^6)^0.5 and integrate the resulted polynomial it finally gives a polynomial p(a, b) with infinite term. Is this helpful?

Answer (score 2):

HINT.-An old theorem of Chebyshev about binomial integrals $\int x^m(a+bx^n)^p$ establishes that it is solvable by elementary functions only in the three following cases:$$\begin{cases} p\in \mathbb Z\\ \frac{m+1}{n}\in \mathbb Z\\\frac{m+1}{n}+p\in\mathbb Z\end{cases}$$ In your integral all of the corresponding values $\frac{1}{2},\frac{0+1}{6}$ and $\frac{0+1}{6}+\frac{1}{2}$ are not in $\mathbb Z$.

Answer (score 0):

As said in comments, the antiderivative is quite messy (involving elliptic integral of the first kind) plus many nasty terms.

For the definite integral, as Raffaele commented,
$$I=\int^{b}_{0}\sqrt{a-x^6}\,dx=b\,\sqrt{a} \, _2F_1\left(-\frac{1}{2},\frac{1}{6};\frac{7}{6};\frac{b^6}{a}\right)$$ provided that $b\geq 0\land \left((\Re(a)>0\land \Im(a)\neq 0)\lor \Re(a)>b^6\right)$.

Setting $b^6=k a$ gives $$a^{-2/3}\,I= k^{1/6} \, _2F_1\left(-\frac{1}{2},\frac{1}{6};\frac{7}{6};k\right)\qquad (0 \leq k \leq 1)$$ where the rhs has a nice looking shape.